# Find the column which are taking max space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Is it possible in JQuery or JavaScript to find thoes rows of a HTML table whose columns are taking max space.

**like in the below image**

- for column 1, 3rd row is taking max space
- for column 2, 1st row is taking max space
- for column 3, 2nd row is taking max space

[image]

Comment: Do you have fixed width in css?

Comment: no its a simple html table without any css style

Comment: can you show us what you have done so far

Comment: This will be a bad way but you can loop over table and check for max width

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9uy2qa0y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`td`s will have same width. You will have to add a wrapper `div` with **`display: inline-block`**. This will enforce `div` to take with of content.

Then you will have to loop over `columns` and inside it again on `rows` and neglect header and calculate width and add class

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/9uy2qa0y/1/)

```js
$(function() {
  var $tr = $("table tr").not(':eq(0)');
  var len = $tr.eq(1).find('td').length;
  for (var col = 0; col < len; col++) {
    var _el = null;
    var _width = 0;
    for (var row = 0; row < $tr.length; row++) {
      var curEl = $tr.eq(row).find('td:eq(' + (col) + ')');
      var divWidth = curEl.find('div:first').width()
      if (divWidth > _width) {
        _width = divWidth;
        _el = curEl
      }
    }
    _el.addClass('red-border')
  }
})
```

```css
.red-border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Table Header11</th>
    <th>Table Header11111</th>
    <th>Table Header111</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        Table cell111
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        Table cell1111
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        Table cell111111
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        Table cell11111</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        Table cell111
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        Table cell11
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Note:** I was lazy, so I added this in css `table div`. Please add a custom class or a proper selector that does not overrides everything